# Breaking an axis and shortening graphs in R

Tags: r, graph

I am currently trying to add an axis break and shorten the x axis to make a BA plot (drawn using methcomp) look a bit neater.

I have managed to insert a break using axis.break but cannot workout how to shorten or remove part of the axis

```
library(MethComp)


comp <- read.csv("HIVVL.csv")
comp
co <- Meth(comp, y=c("Abbot","Qiagen"))

BA.plot(co, pl.type="", dif.type="const", grid=TRUE, eqn=FALSE, repl.conn=TRUE, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")

axis.break(axis=1, breakpos=1250000, style="slash", brw=0.02)
```

My scale runs from 0 to 3000000, last data point is around 1000000 so I would like a break from around 1250000 to 2750000.

Comment: maybe `gap.plot` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Can `gap.plot` be used to introduce breaks into pre-existing plots?

Comment: With rare exception,  there are **no** `R` graphics tools which allow modification of an existing plot. That's not the paradigm.  Since it's trivial to re-execute a few plotting commands, we all get used to redrawing as desired. If you can't reproduce the output style of `BA.plot`, you may have to consider splitting your plotting window into 2 subsections and sending two separate `BA.plot` commands to each in turn. See `?par` for some info on this.